# Filepond upload button not letting users select images from mobile devices only letting them capture new photos

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filepond

I'm using the vue-filepond library to setup image uploads.

I'm using these versions:

```
"filepond": "^4.30.3",
"filepond-plugin-file-validate-type": "^1.2.6",
"filepond-plugin-image-preview": "^4.6.10",
"vue-filepond": "^7.0.2",
```

This is my code:

```
  // Import Vue FilePond
  import vueFilePond from 'vue-filepond'

  // Import FilePond styles
  import 'filepond/dist/filepond.min.css'

  // Import FilePond plugins
  // Please note that you need to install these plugins separately

  // Import image preview plugin styles
  import 'filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.css'

  // Import image preview and file type validation plugins
  import FilePondPluginFileValidateType from 'filepond-plugin-file-validate-type'
  import FilePondPluginImagePreview from 'filepond-plugin-image-preview'

  // Create component
  const FilePond = vueFilePond(
          FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
          FilePondPluginImagePreview
  );

export default {
  components: {
    BreezeAuthenticatedLayout,
    BreezeButton,
    BreezeInput,
    BreezeLabel,
    Head,
    FilePond,
  },
}
```

Template:

```
<file-pond
    name="image_url"
    ref="pond"
    label-idle="Drop files here or <span class='filepond--label-action'>Browse</span>"
    :allow-multiple="false"
    accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
    v-bind:files="myFiles"
/>
```

It works great on desktop but when I try it from android devices it's not letting me choose any photos, goes straight to camera capture.

Comment: I'd start by removing the `accepted-file-types` property to see if that makes a difference. You can additionally experiment with the `capture-method` attribute, it should set the `capture` attribute on the internal file input element. I'd further advise to inspect the HTML to see the file input element and its attributes, you can try if a plain HTML file input element yields the same results.

Comment: Best to try with a plain HTML file input element first, and then transfer the settings over to FilePond if everything works.